# ISNULL with PIVOT in SQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot

With pivot, I need to replace all null values and 0 values with a dash. I started with getting rid of null values:

```
  SELECT FunctionCode, ISNULL(Col1, '-') AS Col1, ISNULL(Col2, '-') AS Col2
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Company, FunctionCode, [Count]
    FROM MyTable
  ) AS D
  PIVOT
  (
    SUM([Count])
    FOR Company IN (Col1, Col2)
  ) PIV;
```

For some reason, NULL is replaced with 0 instead of '-'. What can I try next?

Comment: I guess Col1 and Col2 are INT data type? Maybe try also `CAST` it to some `VARCHAR`

Comment: What are the data types of Col1 and Col2

Comment: @Darka Col1 and Col2 should contain SUM of [Count], which is INT. I am not sure how and where to do CAST.

Comment: @DavidShochet in same place where you check `ISNULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SUM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) can only operate on the numeric data types.

The numeric data types have a [higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190309.aspx) than any textual data type<sup>1</sup>.

So the `-` is converted to a number, e.g.:

```
select CONVERT(int,'-')
```

Produces the result `0`.

So, the solution is to convert your values to a textual type.

```
SELECT FunctionCode, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),Col1), '-') AS Col1,
                     ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),Col2), '-') AS Col2
...
```

And with `0`s dealt with also:

```
SELECT FunctionCode, ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),NULLIF(Col1,0)), '-') AS Col1,
                     ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),NULLIF(Col2,0)), '-') AS Col2
...
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This doesn't, technically, matter here because `ISNULL` doesn't follow the type rules - it always tries to convert its second argument to the same type as the first. But since the problem is the type of the first argument, the same fix applies.

Precedence would have mattered were we to be using [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190349.aspx) instead of `ISNULL`, which is usually preferred.

Comment: Thanks, this works... May I ask you how to do the same for 0 values?

Comment: `NULLIF(Col1,0)` instead of `Col1` in those expressions will first convert any `0`s to be `NULL`s, and then the existing remainder of the expression will deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example:

When `INT` type column set dash, then it becomes 0:

`SELECT ISNULL( CAST(NULL AS INT), '-' )`

But if we `CAST` it to some `VARCHAR` then it is normal dash :

`SELECT ISNULL( CAST( CAST(NULL AS INT) AS VARCHAR(100)), '-' )`